# How to use raw file descriptor even after destroying boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

Suppose, I assigned any raw fd in boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket type, so could I again retrieve raw fd from this to send data again?

I mean does destruction of boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket ensures that fd will also be closed, and if yes, then how could I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably create the socket manually, and use the `posix::stream_descriptor` instead:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html

**Update**:

As the documentation reflects, there is no custom destructor for `(basic_)stream_descriptor` and - hence - the `fd` assigned will not be closed on destruction. (I briefly checked the base classes for completeness).

Comment: @garima721 to the edited comment: clarified my answer

Comment: `class Comm {
private: 
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor> socket;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
public:
Comm(int fd1)
{
this->socket.reset(new boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor(io_service)); this->socket->assign(fd1); 
}; ` 

And, fd is created using 
`int fd1 = accept(socketHandle, (sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size);`

Now if "Comm" class is destroyed, will fd not close?

Comment: Could you please give an example, I am unable to use boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor

Comment: You can probably [search for examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+posix+stream_descriptor) on SO